# Excel Pivot table not to count blanks

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365, pivot-table

[image]

In my Pivot table (columns - count) - I am trying to count where ever there are no blanks - these are strings (not numbers). So wherever there is a non-blank value - count - if only 100 cells have a value (in a column) - report 100.
My pivot table does simple sigma count on columns. So if you see picture - all counts are exactly the same - as it is also counting blanks. (Sole purpose of my pivot table is count/report the missing values (count thereof).

I am using excel O365 MSO 16. Once upon a time *(if I recall correctly)* - there was an option exclude blanks - I cant seem to find that.

How do I accomplish this - right now it counts everything (value or blank).

Comment: Not counting empty cells is the default behavior. Please edit your post and include screenshots of some sample data and the pivot table setup showing the problem.

Comment: @FlexYourData -  Done

Comment: @Sam-T - can we see a screenshot of the source data, not just the pivot? Are the cells truly empty, or are they formulas which return "" ? A simple workaround is to add a helper column to the source data which evaluates to 1 or 0, then sum those.

Comment: Truly empty (blanks)